# Dynamically Create an ID based on an Input Name

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I'd like to know how to dynamically generate an ID on every input tag based off of it's name.  I have to do this using javascript only - Not jQuery.

So, for example, if I have the following text inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="input1" value="">
<input type="text" name="input2" value="">
<input type="text" name="input3" value="">
```

I'd like to end up with this:

```
<input id="input1" type="text" name="input1" value="">
<input id="input2" type="text" name="input2" value="">
<input id="input3" type="text" name="input3" value="">
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain JS, you can get the elements basis of tag name.
And then set the id attribute for that element

```
function setinputIds() { 
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var i=0;i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var id = inputs[i].getAttribute('name');
        inputs[i].setAttribute("id", id);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why "hidden" in the assignment?

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var ii=0, item; item = inputs[ii]; ii++) {
    item.id = item.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use a for loop to iterate name and insert id like this:

```
for(i=1;i<4;i++){
document.getElementsByName('input'+i).id='input'+i;
}
```